# HX711 and 3 load cells

Tags: esp8266, load-cell

I am doing a small project with ESP32 and HX711 and I need to have 3 load cells.

Like this one:

[image]

I am totally newbie in electronics, my ground is programming.

What I found are projects with 1, 2 or 4 load cells connected together.

I need to have 3 load cells , it is to be used as scale for a cylinder.

Is it possible to be done with HX711? How?

EDIT
Best I could find:
[Load Cell](https://www.faranux.com/product/50kg-body-load-cell-weighting-sensor-resistance-strain-half-bridge/)

[HX711 Datasheet](https://storage.googleapis.com/stateless-www-faranux-com/2018/02/bad5cab0-hx711_english.pdf)

Comment: Please edit your question and add links to the datasheets (not the Amazon / AliExpress catalog pages) for the devices in question.

Comment: _"I need to have 3 load cells"_ why?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I need to create a scale for a cylynder, small one, and 4 is complicated, 3 would be ideal. It is not going to be a platform, it will be 3 round supports connected to a central eletronics below the cylynder. So 3 would be best.

Comment: @Transistor added as requested. I could not find for the load cell, I placed from a site that sells it but have good references.

Answer (score 2):

just wire all 3 load cells in parallel. The output will be an average of the 3 cells, so the weight distribution shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The HX711 has two inputs, A and B channels. This would support two load cells.

If three load cells are needed then you could put on load cell on each HX711 or two load cells on one HX711 and the last load cell on the A channel of a second HX711

You will need two HX711's minimum

If you combine two load cells on one HX711, both bridges Vcc are connected to Avdd and the sense± to INB+ and INB-

[image]