# Two load cells on one HX711

Tags: load-cell

I need to read 4 full-bridge load cells about 10 times per second. Are there any drawbacks of [connecting two cells](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/463172/187920) to A and B channels of HX711 and alternating reading between them?

I understand that I will loose the precision (because I'd have to set the data rate to 80SPS) and resolution (because of lower gain on channel B). However what I am concerned about, is if parallel connection of two cells to excitation voltage will introduce cross-talk that will further affect the results.

UPDATE:

The 500kg load cells connected to [HX711 breakout boards](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13879) with 1.5m shielded cables. The breakout boards are mounted on custom STM32 controller PCB for prototyping. In the end I am planning on integrating recommended application schematics from [HX711 datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/813/hx711_english-1022875.pdf) directly into controller board.

The reason I am asking the question instead of simply doing some testing is that Sparkfun breakouts have additional filtering in channel A sensing lines and a lot of filtering/bypassing on avdd/vcc lines, that I was not planning on incorporating into final product.

I simply want to know if I need 4 of these on the board or can get by with only 2, before I begin routing and ordering the PCBs.

Comment: Show schematic and intended layout pls.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I've updated the question with additional details. The schematics is the same as in the first link in the question.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 any comments? more info required?

Comment: I can’t come up with any solid advice, but it is easier to overdesign and DNP redundant parts for noise than add. Cable crosstalk might be a bigger concern from grid E field with 24bit resolution.

Comment: From my experience with these chips so far 24 bit is marketing BS only achievable in lab conditions, so I don't keep illusions on that front. The cables are shielded and they run in four different directions straight from the PCB. My only worry is how (or if) two bridges powered in parallel from same built-in regulator would affect each other.